# Avoid recompiling of ASP.NET web application when changing an .ASCX file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, web-applications, webforms

I have a VB.NET web application in VS2015 that seems to be recompiling whenever I touch an `.ascx` file (then my session is lost and I have to re-authenticate). I don’t have this behavior if I touch an `.aspx` page. I always assumed that I could change the markup without recompiling, and in fact have done it a number of times in previous projects.

I understand the differences between a **web application project** and a **web site project** in ASP.NET. Here we’re talking about a web **application** (project GUID `349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21`) that compiles all the code-behind files into a single DLL.

I have to make a lot of markup and CSS changes that I want to see reflected in the UI without having to recompile, and this is getting quite painful.

Comment: When you `publish` your app, what settings are you using?  Or do you simply copy the compiled files to the server?

Comment: @RickS Forgot to mention that this is all happening while I'm running from Visual Studio, I don't know how it behaves when deployed.